# BigQuery error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'row')

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to fetch the first ID closest to a given date.

I have done this by first filtering date <= date of interest, then PARTITION BY identification and ORDER BY date, and adding a row number. Then select row number = 1 to get the first observation of a person closest to date of interest (assuming 1 person might have multiple IDs within the window of interest.

This is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS rn
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S', date_column) AS date
    FROM
      `data`
  )
  WHERE
    date <= '2022-03-10 00:00:00.000000 UTC'
)
```

Then ultimately, I will filter on rn, but I can't get further. It states the following: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'row'). Any suggestions?

Ignore the names "date", "id" etc.. these are just simplifying for the question.

Comment: Would you need aliases for the subqueries? I don't know google-bigquery but most other databases would need them

Comment: I am not sure, but I will give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following to simplify your query:

```
select *,
  abs(timestamp_diff(date, '2022-01-08 09:01:12', SECOND)) as ts_diff
from sample_data
qualify row_number() OVER (partition by id order by ts_diff asc) = 1
```

This should alleviate your null error which is likely due to one of the date values being empty.
Additionally this will get you a truer representation of `closest` to a given date based on the absolute value, in this case I've passed the date of `2022-01-01`.
`QUALIFY` will eliminate the need to do so many sub-selects in this case.
To productionalize this I would likely define a variable to pass in the actual date.

Here is some documentation on `QUALIFY`:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause

Comment: Hmm thanks for the suggestion! Seems like I still get the "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'row')" error

Comment: Can you share some sample data that is causing the error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, and for me, not the query. it's that some of the data added to the table is causing the error